# IBM MobileFirst Server 8 Farm unresponsive

Tags: tomcat, ibm-mobilefirst

After a few hours of operation, one of the servers' status in "Server Farm Nodes" becomes "unresponsive" and there are multiple errors in the log file:

**Environment:**

OS: Windows Server 2012 R2

MobileFirst Platform: 8.0.41.0 (8.0.0.20161122_1806)

Web Server: Tomcat 8.0.41

Java: Oracle Java 8u121

**Server.xml Configuration:**

```
 <Context docBase="mfpadmin" path="/mfpadmin">
      <Environment name="mfp.admin.push.url"                    value="http://localhost/imfpush" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
      <Environment name="mfp.admin.authorization.server.url"    value="http://localhost/mfp" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
      <Environment name="mfp.push.authorization.client.id"      value="Push_mfp" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
      <Environment name="mfp.push.authorization.client.secret"  value="*********" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
      <Environment name="mfp.admin.authorization.client.id"     value="Admin_mfp" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
      <Environment name="mfp.admin.authorization.client.secret" value="*********" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
      <Environment name="mfp.admin.environmentid"               value="mfp" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
      <Environment name="mfp.topology.platform"                 value="Tomcat" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
      <Environment name="mfp.config.service.password"           value="*********" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
      <Environment name="mfp.config.service.user"               value="configUser_mfpadmin" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
      <Environment name="mfp.topology.clustermode"              value="Farm" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
      <Environment name="mfp.admin.serverid"                    value="MY-SRV1" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/> 
      <Resource name="jdbc/mfpAdminDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource" factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" singleton="true"
      driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@OracleDb:1521:MFPPROD" username="****" password="****" auth="Container" maxTotal="14" maxIdle="10" maxWaitMillis="5000"/>
</Context>
```

Error Log:

```
SEVERE [http-apr-80-exec-5] com.ibm.mfp.admin.util.ResponseUtil.errorImpl FWLSE3000E: A server error was detected.
 <openjpa-2.4.1-r422266:1730418 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: IO Error: Socket read timed out {prepstmnt 701323185 SELECT t0.ID, t0.API_VERSION, t0.LATEST_FINISHED_TRANS, t1.ID, t1.APP_SERVER_ID, t1.DESCRIPTION, t2.ID, t2.API_VERSION, t2.LATEST_FINISHED_TRANS, t2.LATEST_TRANS, t2.NAME, t2.SYNC_STATUS, t1.STATUS, t1.TIME_CREATED, t1.TIME_UPDATED, t1.TYPE, t1.USER_NAME, t0.NAME, t0.SYNC_STATUS FROM PROJECT t0, TRANSACTIONS t1, PROJECT t2 WHERE (t0.NAME = ?) AND t0.LATEST_TRANS = t1.ID(+) AND t1.PROJECT_ID = t2.ID(+)} [code=17002, state=08006]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:5003)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4963)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:133)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:107)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:59)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedSQLStoreQuery$PreparedSQLExecutor.executeQuery(PreparedSQLStoreQuery.java:139)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1011)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:869)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:800)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:541)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:274)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:290)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.jpa.helper.ProjectEntityHelper.getProject(ProjectEntityHelper.java:64)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.jpa.datastore.JPAStoreManager.getProject(JPAStoreManager.java:440)
    at com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.v2.ApplicationService.getAllApplications(ApplicationService.java:258)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:151)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:65)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
    at com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:43)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.filter.HSTSFilter.doFilter(HSTSFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2508)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2497)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: IO Error: Socket read timed out {prepstmnt 701323185 SELECT t0.ID, t0.API_VERSION, t0.LATEST_FINISHED_TRANS, t1.ID, t1.APP_SERVER_ID, t1.DESCRIPTION, t2.ID, t2.API_VERSION, t2.LATEST_FINISHED_TRANS, t2.LATEST_TRANS, t2.NAME, t2.SYNC_STATUS, t1.STATUS, t1.TIME_CREATED, t1.TIME_UPDATED, t1.TYPE, t1.USER_NAME, t0.NAME, t0.SYNC_STATUS FROM PROJECT t0, TRANSACTIONS t1, PROJECT t2 WHERE (t0.NAME = ?) AND t0.LATEST_TRANS = t1.ID(+) AND t1.PROJECT_ID = t2.ID(+)} [code=17002, state=08006]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:218)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:202)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$700(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:58)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection$LoggingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:1117)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:268)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$CancelPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JDBCStoreManager.java:1800)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:258)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedSQLStoreQuery$PreparedSQLExecutor.executeQuery(PreparedSQLStoreQuery.java:118)
    ... 91 more
```

Comment: Looks like the mfp.admin.push.url and mfp.admin.authorization.server.url properties did not contain the port number.  The default for Tomcat is 8080 but you can check in your server.xml for the correct port.

Comment: There is no port because in my setup tomcat runs on port 80. So the configuration is correct.

Comment: Looks like you are losing connection with your admin database - "Socket read timed out". Anything closing out idle connections?

Comment: This is what I suspect also, but how can I troubleshoot/prove this? What I know is that the database server is located in another network zone and perhaps there is something in between (network equipment) that causes this. I asked the network administrator and he said "they are not blocking anything..." Any advice on how to prove/test this? any documentation perhaps?